# Why use 576 configurations for two-qubit process tomography?

Tags: quantum-process-tomography

In the paper ["Efficient Measurement of Quantum Dynamics via Compressive Sensing" Shabani Et. al (2011)](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.106.100401)  [[arXiv:0910.5498](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0910.5498.pdf)], The full process tomography of two-photon is performed as: Preparing 16 pairwise combinations of the 4 input states $\{|H\rangle,|V\rangle,|D\rangle,|R\rangle\}$ and, for each input, measuring 36 two-qubit combinations of the observables $\{|H\rangle,|V\rangle,|D\rangle,|A\rangle,|R\rangle,|L\rangle\}, \quad$ where $|D(A)\rangle=(|H\rangle$ $\pm  |V\rangle) / \sqrt{2}$ and $\mid R(L)\rangle=(|H\rangle \pm i| V\rangle) / \sqrt{2}$. These $16\times 36=576$ input-output configurations represent an overcomplete set which allows the best possible estimate of the quantum process, denoted $\chi_{576}$.

Why are 36 pairs of observables for each input state used here?